# MYsql insert statement error

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm getting a mysql error when running an insert statement. The error is:

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. The insert has 5 values, BUT the comment id is set to AUTO INC

The insert statement looks like this:

```
insert INTO comments (post_id, comment_name, comment_email, comment_text, status) VALUES ('78', 'm man', 'mon@mon.com', 'testh' 'unapprove')
```

The table looks like this

```
1) comment_id       int(10)     AUTO_INCREMENT  
2) post_id          int(10)                 
3) comment_name     varchar(100)
4) comment_email    varchar(100)  
5) comment_text     (text)  
6) status           (text)
```

Can anyone help? many thanks for your efforts

Comment: You're missing a comma in the values clause.

Answer (score 2):

You have make a mistake. You forget to set the comma between all values. Change you query from:

```
insert INTO comments (post_id, comment_name, comment_email, comment_text, status) VALUES ('78', 'm man', 'mon@mon.com', 'testh' 'unapprove')
```

to

```
insert INTO comments (post_id, comment_name, comment_email, comment_text, status) VALUES ('78', 'm man', 'mon@mon.com', 'testh', 'unapprove')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add comma after 'testh' since it it a value for comment_text field.

```
insert INTO comments (post_id, comment_name, comment_email, comment_text, status) VALUES 
                     ('78', 'm man', 'mon@mon.com', 'testh', 'unapprove')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your query to this

```
insert INTO comments VALUES (NULL, '78', 'm man', 'mon@mon.com', 'testh',  'unapprove')
```